# Install Ffmpeg on Mac OS El Capitan

Tags: mac, ffmpeg, osx-el-capitan

Someone have a solution to install ffmpeg on a old Mac OS El Capitan ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where did it fail? What error messages did you get?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.